# Testing Rails model method with rspec

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rspec

I'm confused as to why this test isn't working. It only works when I add a return value to the stubbed `bar` method. However, it is not expected to have a return value, so I only want to test `bar` is called within `foo`.

```
class Event < ApplicationRecord
  def foo
    bar
  end
end
```

This test does not work.

```
describe Event, type: :model do
  it 'calls bar' do
    event = create(:event)
    
    allow(event).to receive(:bar)

    expect(event.foo).to receive(:bar)
  end
end


Error message:
Failure/Error: expect(event.foo).to receive(:bar)
     
  (nil).bar(*(any args))
     expected: 1 time with any arguments
     received: 0 times with any arguments
```

When I change the test to add a return value the test works.

```
describe Event, type: :model do
  it 'calls bar' do
    event = create(:event)
    
    allow(event).to receive(:bar).and_return(true)

    expect(event.foo).to eq(true)
  end
end
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is a lot of things wrong in this picture.

Lets start with the method:

```
class Event < ApplicationRecord
  def foo
    bar
  end
end
```

When you call `Event.new.foo` you're calling `#bar` on `self` which is the instance of Event. Not on the method `foo`.

If you do `expect(event.foo).to receive(:bar)` you're setting the expectation on the return value of the method which of course doesn't work.

If you want to test that calling foo calls bar you can use `expect(obj).to recieve :method_name` if you want to set the expectation before hand:

```ruby
describe Event, type: :model do
  it 'calls bar' do
    event = create(:event)
    expect(event).to receive(:bar)
    event.foo
  end
end
```

Note that you don't have to use `allow(event).to receive(:bar)` unless you want to stub the method. `expect(event).to receive(:bar)` wraps the method so that RSpec can track the calls to the method.

The example will fail unless the expected method is called.

Or you can use a spy if you prefer the arrage, act, assert pattern:

```ruby
describe Event, type: :model do
  it 'calls bar' do
    # arrange
    event = create(:event) 
    allow(event).to receive(:bar) 
    # act
    event.foo
    # assert
    expect(foo).to have_recieved(:bar)
  end
end
```

Answer (score -1):

Found the answer after posting my question:

```
describe Event, type: :model do
  it 'calls bar' do
    event = create(:event)
    
    allow(event).to receive(:bar)

    expect(event).to receive(:bar)

    event.foo
  end
end
```